# How to Call onPostExecute only after Completing CallBack Methods of doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback

I have a class **LoginTask** which is a subclass of AsyncTask. I used that to execute login functionality. Simply my **LoginTask** looks like this

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<JsonObject,Void,String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       //Codes to show progressDialog
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(JsonObject... params) {

     Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("--URL TO POST JSON DATA--")
                .setJsonObjectBody(params[0])
                .asJsonObject()
                .withResponse()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {

                        if (result != null) {
                            if (result.getHeaders().code() == 200) {

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else if (result.getHeaders().code() == 401) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something wrong check connection !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        return "some message";

     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        super.onPostExecute(string);

        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //TODO Something

        }

    }
}
```

**What I want and What was happened :**

- I want to call `onPostExecute` Only after getting the result from `FutureCallback` method But when I debug the app It is directly returning the value and `onPostExecute` Method called Immediately before `FutureCallback` method.
- I have written code to Execute **LoginTask** at Login Button pressed Event, I want to show the `ProgressDialog` each time when Button is pressed, But the problem is **ProgressDialog** is shown only at the first time, It didn't appear when I pressed the Button second time.
- I want to set some message to a variable and return that to `onPostExecute` method so that I can handle specific tasks based on the value of String parameter, But `FutureCallback` is called only after executing the whole Task.

**Any Kind of Suggestions will be appreciated.**

Comment: try without  `AsyncTask` and do whatever in `onCompleted`

Comment: @kishorejethava Ohh I'm sorry thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are calling another thread inside asynctask. So whats happening is when the new thread is getting called. Asynctask is not waiting for your ion's thread to complete and so it is going to onPostExecute.

I think you don't need a asynctask here because Ion is already making the request asyncronously. Whatever you are doing inside onPostExecute(), you can put that inside onComplete() of the ion's call.

Comment: Thanks.. I wanted to execute it inside asynctask because there was many hidden codes before calling ION +1 for your answer....

Answer (score 1):

Do like this,

```
[Codes to show progressDialog]

Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load("--URL TO POST JSON DATA--")
            .setJsonObjectBody(params[0])
            .asJsonObject()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() 
{
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {
if(progressDialog.isShowing()){

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        //TODO Something

    }
                    if (result != null) {
                        if (result.getHeaders().code() == 200) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else if (result.getHeaders().code() == 401) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something wrong check connection !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpul suggestion.. But It is solved already by First answer +1 for ur suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`onCompleted()` method you are passing in `setCallback()` method is a callback method that is an asynchronous call so this callback will be invoked when response is returned from server and its takes time that is why your `onPostExecute` method is called before `futureTask`.

`Ion` lib already uses async calls so you do not need to use AsyncTask. You just need to do following:

```
Ion.with(MainActivity.this) 
            .load("--URL TO POST JSON DATA--") 
            .setJsonObjectBody(params[0])
            .asJsonObject() 
            .withResponse() 
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override 
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {

                    if (result != null) {
                        if (result.getHeaders().code() == 200) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else if (result.getHeaders().code() == 401) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else { 
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something wrong check connection !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            });
```